# Density of Primes in an interval

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Is it possible to characterize all or at least some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there are more than $k$ primes between $k^2$ and $\lfloor k^2/2\rfloor$? Or is it possible to characterize all or at least some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there are at most $k$ primes between $k^2$ and $\lfloor k^2/2\rfloor$?

Comment: The first answer is great.... as a comment, you’re asking about intervals where the density is $k/(k^2/2)=2/k$ or more... given that the PNT says the density is $\sim 1/\log k$, you should expect all sufficiently large intervals to have this property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k \geq 16$. By Wikipedia bounds on the prime-counting function, $\pi(k^2/2) <1.25506\frac{k^2}{4\ln{k}-2\ln{2}} \leq 1.25506\frac{k^2}{3.5\ln{k}}$, and $\pi(k^2) \geq \frac{k^2}{2\ln{k}}$. Thus $\pi(k^2)-\pi(k^2/2) \geq \frac{k^2}{\ln{k}}(0.5-1.25506/3.5)$. So as soon as $\frac{k}{\ln{k}} (0.5-1.25506/3.5) > 1$, your statement holds.

Using Wolfram, we can thus see that the statement holds for all $k \geq 22$, and the smaller numbers can be tested manually.

Comment: Wolfram is just to find for which $k$ one has $k/\ln{k}$ greater than the reciprocal of that number (since the function is increasing for $k \geq 3$). The bounds are the first available on Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function , section “Inequalities”.